# How to create buttons based on a condition?

Tags: javascript, html

I wold like to create buttons based on conditions.
For example, for the term `yellow` create 3 buttons, for `blue` term create 5 buttons and so on.

```
// color = yellow

if (color == 'yellow')
{
   //create 3 button on html
}
if (color == 'blue')
{
  //create 5 button on html
}

//and so on
```

> Result on HTML

```
   <a href="1" class="btn btn-default">1</a> 
   <a href="2" class="btn btn-default">2</a> 
   <a href="3" class="btn btn-default">3</a>
```

Comment: I would recommend researching "create element". You already have the other building blocks (just remember that `if` is lowercase).

Comment: also = is assignment, == or === is comparison

Comment: Are you using any javascript frameworks such as React OR Angular to achieve this? OR are you talking about the vanilla javascript? The solution will be depending upon these factors at least.

Comment: look at the createElement method - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp also check you equality comparison in javascript it should be == or even ===

Comment: @majita [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) is a better resource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you meant this:

```js
const colors = {
  "yellow": 3,
  "blue": 5
};
[...document.querySelectorAll(".btnContainer")].forEach(function(container) {
  const color = container.getAttribute("data-color");
  const numLinks = colors[color]
  container.style.backgroundColor=color;
  for (let i = 0; i < numLinks; i++) {
    let a = document.createElement('a');
    a.textContent = (i + 1);
    a.href = (i + 1);
    a.classList.add('btn', 'btn-default');
    container.appendChild(a);
  }
})
```

```css
a { opacity:.7; margin:5px }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="btnContainer" data-color="yellow"></div>
<div class="btnContainer" data-color="blue"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create link like this

```js
var a = document.createElement('a');
var linkText = document.createTextNode("my title text");
a.appendChild(linkText);
a.title = "my title text";
a.href = "http://example.com";
document.body.appendChild(a);
```

Comment: Where is the "based on a condition"?

Comment: @mplungjanhe should put this code inside the condition

Comment: I know. But that seems to be more the question than how to create an element